# how to add image and text box on a div on click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want image and textbox on click. i use some code but its not proper working

```js
$(function () {
    $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function () {
        
      
        var textBox = document.createElement("input");
        $("input").addClass("textbox")
        //$("input").addClass("textbox")
        
        $('.rose').append(textBox);

        $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function ()
        {alert("ss")
        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
        $("img").addClass("mynasicondiv")
            img.src ="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg"  
            $('.rose').html(img);
        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't really get, what are you asking on.

Comment: @premysi  i want a text box and image on click a button

Comment: Specify it in question please

Comment: Your snippet has missing closing brackets and parenthesis. Please fix that.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný each lick of the button add to the image and textbox i use the code but its not proper working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not use two click events and make use of append function to achieve what you want.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function () {
        
        var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textBox"/>';
        
        $('.rose').append(textBox);
        
        
        var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg"></img>';

        $('.rose').append(img);
        
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rose"></div>
<button class="plusicondiv">Add Element</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Improvements done here:

- No two click event binding here.
- Parenthesis and indentation needed fixes.
- Setting the classname properly.
- Use append instead of .html

```js
$(function () {
  $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function() {


    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.className = 'textbox';

    $('.rose').append(textBox);

    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.className = "mynasicondiv";
    img.src = "https://get.asp.net/images/yeoman.png";
    $('.rose').append(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='plusicondiv'>Add image</button>
<div class='rose'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to apply click event for two times

```js
$(function () {
    $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function () {
        
      
        var textBox = document.createElement("input");
        //textBox.addClass("textbox");
        $("input").addClass("textbox")
        
        $('.rose').append(textBox);

        //$('.plusicondiv').on('click',function(){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        $("img").addClass("mynasicondiv")
            img.src ="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/olympics/photos/o16/archive/MTZSPDEC74T805NJ_213x120.JPG"  
            $('.rose').append(img);
       //});
     });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rose"></div>
<input type="button" class="plusicondiv" value="plusicondiv">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<button class='addmore' id='addmore'>Add Dynamic Data</button>
<div class='data' id="data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('addmore').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var text_element = document.createElement("input");
var img = document.createElement('img');
var div_data = document.getElementById('data');

img.setAttribute('src', '1.jpeg');

$('.data').append(img);
$('.data').append(text_element);
});

</script>
```